# MySQL: All parts of primary key must be NOT NULL; if you need NULL in a key, use UNIQUE instead fivem

Tags: sql

can someone fix the whole sql for me because i don't really understand sql

this is for my fivem server

https://www.mediafire.com/file/4hqnihgpxu7gfsd/mdt.sql/file

Comment: What is the error

Comment: SQL Error (1171): All parts of a PRIMARY KEY must be NOT NULL; if you need NULL in a key, use UNIQUE insteadNotice: You can disable the "Stop on errors in batch mode" option to ignore such errors

Comment: Remove `NULL` from `mdt_data` table of the `cid` column

Comment: Now i have nev error 

SQL Error (1064): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '  `information` MEDIUMTEXT DEFAULT NULL,  `tags` TEXT NOT NULL,  `gallery`' at line 3Notice: You can disable the "Stop on errors in batch mode" option to ignore such errors

Comment: Can you donwload my file and edit all errors and reupload again?

Comment: My sql server version is 5.7.36 and database is and collation is utf8_general_ci

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mdt_data` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `cid` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
  `information` MEDIUMTEXT DEFAULT NULL,
  `tags` TEXT NOT NULL,
  `gallery` TEXT NOT NULL,
  `jobtype` VARCHAR(25) DEFAULT 'police',
  `pfp` TEXT DEFAULT NULL,
  `fingerprint` VARCHAR(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`cid`),
  KEY `id` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mdt_bulletin` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` TEXT NOT NULL,
  `desc` TEXT NOT NULL,
  `author` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `time` varchar(20)  NOT NULL,
  `jobtype` VARCHAR(25) DEFAULT 'police',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mdt_reports` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `author` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `title` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `type` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `details` text DEFAULT NULL,
  `tags` text DEFAULT NULL,
  `officersinvolved` text DEFAULT NULL,
  `civsinvolved` text DEFAULT NULL,
  `gallery` text DEFAULT NULL,
  `time` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `jobtype` varchar(25) DEFAULT 'police',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mdt_bolos` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `author` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `title` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `plate` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `owner` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `individual` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `detail` text DEFAULT NULL,
  `tags` text DEFAULT NULL,
  `gallery` text DEFAULT NULL,
  `officersinvolved` text DEFAULT NULL,
  `time` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `jobtype` varchar(25) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'police',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mdt_convictions` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `cid` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `linkedincident` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `warrant` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `guilty` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `processed` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `associated` varchar(50) DEFAULT '0',
  `charges` text DEFAULT NULL,
  `fine` int(11) DEFAULT 0,
  `sentence` int(11) DEFAULT 0,
  `recfine` int(11) DEFAULT 0,
  `recsentence` int(11) DEFAULT 0,
  `time` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mdt_incidents` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `author` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `title` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `details` text NOT NULL,
  `tags` text NOT NULL,
  `officersinvolved` text NOT NULL,
  `civsinvolved` text NOT NULL,
  `evidence` text NOT NULL,
  `time` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `jobtype` varchar(25) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'police',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mdt_logs` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `text` text NOT NULL,
  `time` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `jobtype` varchar(25) DEFAULT 'police',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mdt_vehicleinfo` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `plate` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `information` text NOT NULL ,
  `stolen` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `code5` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `image` text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mdt_impound` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `vehicleid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `linkedreport` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `fee` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `time` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;
```

made changes in `mdt_data` table and `mdt_vehicleinfo` table

Comment: Big thank you Deepan! i inserted in database with no error

Comment: @Sven I have removed the default value `mdt_vehicleinfo` table columns: `information`, `image`